# Word/phrase/allusion for spreading false intel to catch a mole

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

If I want to find the leak in my agency, I tell twenty people twenty stories and wait to see which emerges.

If I want to find out who's selling my contact info to spammers, I give every company a different email of mine and check which one gets the spam.

If I want to know who's blackmailing people, I tell each suspect about a different potential victim and watch to see who gets blackmailed next.

How can I refer to this strategy without explaining it?

Comment: I’ve always found that the most effective strategy at catching moles to be a feline one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Disinformation***

"Disinformation is intentionally false or inaccurate information that is spread deliberately.[1] It is an act of deception and false statements to convince someone of untruth. Disinformation should not be confused with misinformation, information that is unintentionally false."  Quoted from Wikipedia

There was an elaborate program of **disinformation** in WWII to convince the Germans that the invasion would **not** be at Normandy, but at Calais.  If you like science fiction, see Connie Willis "All Clear", the sequel to "Blackout".   Strange, I agree to list SF as a reference, but her depiction of WWII in London and key places in England was extraordinarily well researched.

Comment: I should have referenced Wikipedia for the first paragraph quote.  And, thanks for the acceptance.

Comment: You should edit your answer to add the Wikipedia reference.

Comment: @ab2:  I think **disinformation** just means "false intel".  The disinformation could have many purposes not including catching a mole.  I don't know of a single word or term meaning "false intel to catch a mole".

Comment: @James I am packing for a trip, so I can't pursue this farther than this message:  See "War of the Moles: The Lessons of LeCarre" at https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=disinformation%2C+LeCarre.

Comment: The email example in the OP's second paragraph is planting *true intel* as those are actual email addresses. They are not disinformation, *per se*.

Answer (score 2):

Moles and other vermin are often caught with [bait](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bait).

As a noun, *bait* is

> a poisoned lure used in exterminating pests. (definition 2)
>
> an allurement; enticement (definition 3)

As a verb, *to bait* is

> to entice by deception or trickery so as to entrap or destroy (definition 8)
>
> to attract, tempt, or captivate (definition 9)

The fine *disinformation* answer from @ab2 leans more toward the *false intel*, while the *bait* answer leans more toward *to catch a mole*.

Comment: Good answer.  I am going to reread "Tinker, Tailor, Soldier, Spy"  on the plane tomorrow.

Comment: Not surprising that the Spy Master, le Carré, would end up taking a part of these answers.